# Delete xml tags that don't contain any data

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have a very large xml file and i need to delete tags without any data.

```
       NameFree>Linjamäki, Anna Maria</NameFree> -->should not bee deleted

       NameFree></NameFree>  --> should be deleted
```

much appreciated

newbee

Comment: Do you want to delete only the tag or the whole line?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with the find and replace tool:

[image: example]

- Open search and replace with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Set search mode to regular expression
- Enter `<(\w+)>(<\/?\w+>)*<\/\1>` in `find what` field
- Leave `replace with` field empty
- Click `replace all`

This will only remove the empty XML tag, nothing more.

Output:

```
<NameFree>Linjamäki, Anna Maria</NameFree> -->should not bee deleted

  --> should be deleted
```

Answer (score -1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\s*<(\w+).*?>\s*</\1>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\s*         # 0 or more spaces
<           # literally <
(\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word character, tagname
.*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy, optional attributes
>           # literally >
\s*         # 0 or more spaces
</          # literally </
\1          # back reference to group 1, the tagname
>           # literally >
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain?